# Use FFMPEG process to get all frame from rtsp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ffmpeg, rtsp

process to run a command that reads a RTSP stream with FFMPEG, and I need to catch each frame to display it in a picturebox; I'm receiving the data in void OnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e), but once I transform e.data to byte[] and I generate the bitmap the app crashes.

my code:

```
private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg";
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i rtsp://user:foscam@50.197.211.181:9826/videoMain -an -vcodec mjpeg -s 640x480 -threads 1 -aspect 16:9 -q:v 2 -updatefirst 1 -b:v 64k -f -";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += OnOutputDataReceived;
        if (!proc.Start())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error starting");
            return;
        }
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
        StreamReader reader = proc.StandardError;
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        proc.Close();
    }

    void OnOutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[e.Data.Length * sizeof(char)];
        System.Buffer.BlockCopy(e.Data.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Bitmap bmp;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
    // CRASH SITE

            bmp = new Bitmap(ms);
        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
```

[Bytes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7Fuz.jpg)

[Crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnYQs.jpg)

Comment: I don't know much about ffmpeg, but if there is any video coming in through streaming, you are receiving multiple frames. And you don't seem to be doing anything to detect the frame terminator at your rendering part

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process image files from a camera, the usage of FFMPEG is not the best way, since you´re adding an independent layer between the device and your .NET code.

You need to use AFORGE.NET, which is built specifically to do it. I made two applications to FOSCAM cameras (a Windows desktop one and WinPhone 7x) and AFORGE was the best choice to them. Unfortunatly, I haven´t the code anymore, but try AFORGE instead insist on FFMPEG (and I guess AFORGE has samples for exporting to FFMPEG).

See here:
http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/

Comment: Aforgenet does not support RTSP as the author kindly stated here: http://www.aforgenet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=2273